# Is it possible to send emails using Javascript by requesting Outlook Exchange Server

Tags: javascript, ajax, email, outlook

I am working on a project and I would like to be able to send out individual emails given customer address(es). Ideally this would all happen in the background as I click a button. I do not want to bring up the mail client form since the number of recipients could potentially be very large and sending the emails one by one would be too painful.

I'm currently using JavaScript, however after some research I found that one cannot directly send emails from JavaScript, but have to send request to mail server through Ajax calls. I've considered third-party APIs such and Mandrill, but I'm not sure about it since the emails might contain sensitive data.

My question is, is it possible to accomplish the task with Outlook Exchange server (I believe that JavaScript has got an API for Office product)?

**UPDATE**

I end up switching to Java Mail API https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/. It only requires a few steps to connect to the server and send emails.

Comment: If you don't want to use a third party API, you're probably better off sending it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

nope, this needs to be done server side. That said there are some services you can use. There were some through Mandrill but they have changed a little since last I used them. I think if you are sending sensitive data that needs to be done through a server.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going to use the java mail api.